# Shinobi Chart on Android (Xamarin) freezes

Tags: android, xamarin, shinobi

I'm trying to implement ShinobiCharts for Android (premium) and everything seems to work fine the first time.  I update data live, using the SimpleDataAdapter.AddAll, a few times, and then stop updating.  I then update other parts of the UI.

Then I try and update the chart again (using AddAll) and it appears "frozen".  If I try and pan, the X Ticks slide past, but the chart itself, and all the data displayed, doesn't move.

The only thing I can think of is removing and re-adding the chart to the parent view, but I thought I'd check if it's possible I'm doing something wrong.

I'm using Xamarin Forms, with a custom renderer to display the chart.  iOS works fine, although it's (obviously?) using a different renderer and data adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  I was trying to update/refresh the chart from a background thread. I moved the call to the UI thread and it's updating and working great.